# Dynamically handle images from the DB in ImageHandler.ashx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, imagehandler

I am working on a blog site. The user can 'browse' through a FileUpload control and select multiple images to be uploaded along with their post. Each post has a unique Message ID in the DB. I have figured out how to insert all of the uploaded files into the DB under one message ID like this: (I insert them as data type 'image')

```
 try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BlogMessages (Title, Message, Date, Author, IPAddress) VALUES (@Title, @Message, @Date, @Author, @IPAddress)", conn);
                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", tbTitle.Text.Trim());
                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", tbMessage.Text.Trim());
                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", tbAuthor.Text.Trim());
                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPAddress", ip);
                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (imageUpload.HasFiles)
                {
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    HttpPostedFile file;

                    SqlCommand maxMessId = new SqlCommand("SELECT Max(MessageID) FROM BlogMessages", conn);
                    lastMessageID = Convert.ToInt32(maxMessId.ExecuteScalar());

                    foreach (var uploadedFile in imageUpload.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        file = uploadedFile; 
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        byte[] byts = ms.ToArray();
                        ms.Dispose();

                        SqlCommand cmdInsertImage = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BlogImages(Image, MessageID) VALUES (@Image, @MessageID)", conn);
                        cmdInsertImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = byts;
                        cmdInsertImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageID", lastMessageID);
                        cmdInsertImage.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        byts = null;
                        cmdInsertImage = null; 


                    }

                }
```

However, I am having trouble dynamically retrieving the images for display in my ImageHandler. It seems that I am able to get all of the images under a specific MessageID and insert them into a dataset, but after that is what I am looking for guidance on, and I have not been able to come up with a working solution through research thus far. Here is the relevant code inside public void Process Request of ImageHandler.ashx.cs:

```
  try
            {
                int messageid = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["mid"]);

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Image from BlogImages WHERE Image IS NOT NULL AND MessageID=" + messageid, conn);
                System.Data.DataSet data = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(data);


                if (data !=null)
                {

                    byte[] result = (byte[])data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageContent"];
                    result.Initialize();
                    context.Response.ContentType = data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageExt"].ToString();
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(result);

                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.WriteFile("No Image");
                }
            }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've done this before, I'll try and dig out some code. Can you just sanity check that the bytes stored in your database can form an image?  Forget the ImageHandler for the time being and do and Image.FromBytes() and save it somewhere to prove what's stored in your DB is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will try to check that. I believe that it can indeed form an image, as one of the many solutions I have tried would display only one out of the three images (usually the first in the line of uploaded images) after they were all pulled from the DB.